# Warning: imagettftext() [function.imagettftext]: Could not find/open font in /home/a2424901/public_html/index.php on line 35

Tags: php, truetype, imagettftext

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'facebook.php';
$app_id = "418907881455014";
$app_secret = "36389d2c4caaf6de86982cb87686a494";
$redirect_uri = 'http://gooogle12.comuf.com';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
        'appId' => $app_id,
        'secret' => $app_secret,
        'cookie' => true
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');

$coded = $_REQUEST['code'];

$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$name = "".$user_profile['name']."";
$fbid = "".$user_profile['id']."";

function RandomLine($filename) {
    $lines = file($filename) ;
    return $lines[array_rand($lines)] ;
}
$reason = RandomLine("reason.txt");  

$canvas = imagecreatefromjpeg ("bg.jpg");                                   // background image file
$black = imagecolorallocate( $canvas, 0, 0, 0 );                         // The second colour - to be used for the text
$font = "Arial.ttf";                                                         // Path to the font you are going to use
$fontsize = 20;                                                             // font size

$birthday = "".$user_profile['birthday']."";
$death = "- ".date('d/m/Y', strtotime( '+'.rand(0, 10000).' days'))."";

imagettftext( $canvas, 22, -1, 110, 120, $black, $font, $name );            // name
imagettftext( $canvas, 22, -1, 110, 170, $black, $font, $birthday );        // birthday
imagettftext( $canvas, 22, -1, 255, 172, $black, $font, $death );           // death
imagettftext( $canvas, 20, -1, 110, 220, $black, $font, $reason );           // reason


$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

//Create an album
$album_details = array(
        'message'=> 'How will you die?',
        'name'=> 'How will you die?'
);
$create_album = $facebook->api('/me/albums', 'post', $album_details);

//Get album ID of the album you've just created
$album_uid = $create_album['id'];

//Upload a photo to album of ID...

$file='img/'.$fbid.'.jpg'; //Example image file

$photo_details = array( 'message'=> 'Find...51', 'image' => '@'.realpath($file));
$upload_photo = $facebook->api('/'.$album_uid.'/photos', 'post', $photo_details);


    enter code here



ImageDestroy( $canvas );

header("Location: http://facebook.com".$fbid."&photoid=".$upphoto."")
?>
```

Well i am using this php code to make a facebook application.I uploaded the font `Arial.ttf`to the root directory of my website. But still i am showing the error- `Warning: imagettftext() [function.imagettftext]: Could not find/open font in /home/a2424901/public_html/index.php on line 35`. I tried changing the case,but i did'nt worked for me. Where i went wrong in this code ?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

[From the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php)

> Depending on which version of the GD library PHP is using, when fontfile does not begin with a leading / then .ttf will be appended to the filename and the library will attempt to search for that filename along a library-defined font path.

This seems to imply that the fontfile should be an absolute path, and if it isn't, the function will append another `.ttf` onto the end of it.

Specify the full path to the font file.

```
$font = "/home/a2424901/public_html/Arial.ttf";
```

Or omit the `.ttf` and use the `GDFONTPATH`.  [The documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) recommends the following:

> In many cases where a font resides in the same directory as the script using it the following trick will alleviate any include problems.

```
putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));
$font = "Arial";
```

Answer (score 18):

To add on to user2724960's answer;
Changing the FontName to `__DIR__ . '/graph/fonts/someFont.ttf'` did it for me.

Full line:

```
$myPicture->setFontProperties(array("FontName"=>__DIR__ .  '/graph/fonts/someFont.ttf',"FontSize"=>14));
```

Don't forget to replace "**someFont**" with the name of your font file (default: "Forgotte")

Comment: it works, thanks.
I thought it was permission issue, but it's not.

Answer (score 11):

My solve (works for me):

```
realpath('here/is/right/path/to/font.ttf');
```

Answer (score 9):

I am also on XAMPP, apparently XAMPP does only support full directory path to the font. This code works both on Windows (XAMPP) and on our providers Linux server:

```
$dir= dirname(realpath(__FILE__));
$sep=DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;   
$font =$dir.$sep.'arial.ttf';
imagettftext($thumb, $size, 0, $y_pos, $size, $textcolor, $font, $txt);
```

(assuming that your font file is in the same directory as your php file)

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. My font name was

> Titr.TTF

and i changed it to

> Titr.ttf

and its worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

it worked for me :
use absolute path

```
$font = 'C:\wamp\www\Persian-txt2img\Vazir-Code.ttf';
$font = mb_convert_encoding($font, 'big5', 'utf-8');

// Add the text
imagettftext($image, 24, 0, 64, 48, $text_color, $font, $text);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using pChart use this:

```
$myPicture->setFontProperties(array("FontName"=>"../fonts/Forgotte.ttf","FontSize"=>11));
```

Answer (score 0):

On GoDaddy (shared hosting, Cpanel), I have to specify the path only *after* the domain:

**My files are here:**

```
URL:  http://example.com/assets/fonts/verdana/verdana.ttf
path:  /home/content/123456/html/example/assets/fonts/verdana/verdana.ttf
```

**PHP code which works:**

```
$font = 'assets/fonts/verdana/verdana.ttf';
```

Using other values for the path did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue while working on localhost (XAMPP).

My solution was:

```
// Set Correct Path to Font File
$fontPath='C:\xampp\htdocs\Adeplay\fonts\Tesox\tesox.ttf';
```

Answer (score -6):

Please check for the font folder under Resources.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.