# Captcha Helper Codeigniter Error - imagettftext(): Could not find/open font

Tags: php, codeigniter, captcha

please help me solve this problem.
I want to use the captcha in my login page using captcha helper in CodeIgniter, but got some error like this :

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: imagettftext(): Could not find/open font
>
> Filename: helpers/captcha_helper.php

=============================================

this is my controller :

```
public function login() {

    $data['captcha'] = $this->set_captcha();
    $this->load->view('access/login', $data);

}

public function set_captcha() {

    $vals = array(
        'img_path'      => './assets/img/captcha/',
        'img_url'       => base_url('assets/img/captcha'),
        'font_path'     => './assets/fonts/Kalam-Regular.ttf',
        'img_width'     => 175,
        'img_height'    => 55,
        'expiration'    => 3600,
        'word_length'   => 5,
        'font_size'     => 17,
        'pool'          => '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz',

        // White background and border, black text and red grid
        'colors'        => array(
            'background' => array(255, 255, 255),
            'border' => array(255, 255, 255),
            'text' => array(160, 160, 160),
            'grid' => array(255, 183, 206)
        )
    );

    $cap = create_captcha($vals);

    return $cap['image'];

}
```

and then I just echo the captcha variable in the view.

the problem is only show in windows (XAMPP) but not in my ubuntu server.
please tell me if any duplicate of this post, I have searched the list of posts & google but did not find the same problem.

Comment: Try this [https://youtu.be/TU_8b9SRe_k]

Comment: I already do the same thing like in your link

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10366726/938436

Comment: @Andy , try to give relative path in img_path & font_path and test it again

Answer (score 0):

it happens to me when i start using xampp for test purpose, so what i did was... i did change to `'font_path' => base_url('system/fonts/texb.ttf'),`

Answer (score 0):

Try to check your php.ini configuration

open and search for `extension=fileinfo`
Add `extension=gd` on the following line after `extension=fileinfo` and then save and close the file.

note: if `extention=gd2` exist put semicolon infront `;extention=gd2`