# imagettftext(): Could not find/open font

Tags: laravel

Can someone help me please. I am using laravel 10 jetstream and deployed in hostinger

> imagettftext(): Could not find/open font

```
if (!function_exists('generateQRCode')) {
    function generateQRCode($appointment)
    {
        $name = $appointment->name;
        $date = $appointment->date;
        $department_name = $appointment->department_name;
        $available_hours = $appointment->available_hours;
        $purpose = $appointment->purpose;
        $qrCode = QrCode::format('png')
            ->size(300)
            ->margin(8)
            ->color(0, 0, 0)
            ->backgroundColor(255, 255, 255)
            ->generate($appointment->id);

        $filename = 'qrcode_' . $appointment->id . '.png';
        // $path = 'C:/Capstone/PLVQueuevms/public/qr_codes/' . $filename;
        $path = public_path('qr_codes/' . $filename);

        file_put_contents($path, $qrCode);

        $image = imagecreatefrompng($path);
        $nameColor = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
        $textTop = 'PLVQueue';
        imagettftext($image, 10, 0, 120, 40, $nameColor, 'arial.ttf', $textTop);
        imagepng($image, $path);

        $image = imagecreatefrompng($path);
        $nameColor = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
        imagettftext($image, 10, 0, 110, 250, $nameColor, 'arial.ttf', $name);
        imagepng($image, $path);

        $image = imagecreatefrompng($path);
        $nameColor = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
        imagettftext($image, 10, 0, 90, 265, $nameColor, 'arial.ttf', $date);
        imagepng($image, $path);

        $image = imagecreatefrompng($path);
        $nameColor = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
        imagettftext($image, 10, 0, 160, 265, $nameColor, 'arial.ttf', $available_hours);
        imagepng($image, $path);

        $image = imagecreatefrompng($path);
        $nameColor = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
        imagettftext($image, 10, 0, 60, 280, $nameColor, 'arial.ttf', $department_name);
        imagepng($image, $path);

        $image = imagecreatefrompng($path);
        $nameColor = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
        imagettftext($image, 10, 0, 60, 295, $nameColor, 'arial.ttf', $purpose);
        imagepng($image, $path);

        return $filename;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning: imagettftext() \[function.imagettftext\]: Could not find/open font in /home/a2424901/public\_html/index.php on line 35](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10366679/warning-imagettftext-function-imagettftext-could-not-find-open-font-in-ho)